# iPhone 6.0 Simulator : Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

When I am running my app in iPhone 6.0 simulator, it is showing

Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

In other simulators it is not there. Why?
What is the meaning of this error?

The navigation flow of my app is like : First my app should show login screen. After entering in to the app, I need to show one view with tabbar. In that view So many buttons will be there, and when we clicking these button it should show respective viewcontrollers without a tabbar. Thats why i added those navigation controllers to the window.

Here is my code for didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];

    [application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];

    Object1 = [[Class1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Class1" bundle:nil];
    tempNav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:Object1];
    tempNav.navigationBar.hidden=YES;
    tempNav.view.frame  = CGRectMake(0.0f, 20.0f, 320.0f, 460.0f);
    self.window addSubview:tempNav.view]; 

    LoginObj = [[Login alloc] initWithNibName:@"Login" bundle:nil];
    navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:LoginObj];
    navController.navigationBar.hidden=YES;
    navController.view.frame  = CGRectMake(0.0f, 20.0f, 320.0f, 460.0f);
    [self.window addSubview:navController.view];

    Obj2 = [[Class2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Class2" bundle:nil];
    navController1=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:Obj2];
    navController1.navigationBar.hidden=YES;
    navController1.view.frame  = CGRectMake(0.0f, 20.0f, 320.0f, 460.0f);
    [self.window addSubview:navController1.view];

    Obj3 = [[Class3 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Class3" bundle:nil];
    navController2=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:Obj3];
    navController2.navigationBar.hidden=YES;
    navController2.view.frame  = CGRectMake(0.0f, 20.0f, 320.0f, 460.0f);
    [self.window addSubview:navController2.view];

    Obj4 = [[Class4 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Class4" bundle:nil];
    navController3=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:Obj4];
    navController3.navigationBar.hidden=YES;
    navController3.view.frame  = CGRectMake(0.0f, 20.0f, 320.0f, 460.0f);
    [self.window addSubview:navController3.view];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;  
}
```

Comment: Can you include your application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions code.  That's probably where this is happening.

Comment: this has shown on all simulators for me, it happens when you add your rootViewController's view to the window, instead of setting the rootViewController property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As wattson12 said, you need to do something like this in your app delegate:

```objc
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.mainViewController = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.mainViewController;    // you need this line!
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

If you haven't explicitly set the `UIWindow` [rootViewController property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWindow/rootViewController), you'll see this message.

If you use Xcode 4.5 to create a new project, it should have this code in the template app delegate.  If you're using a project you created in an earlier version of Xcode, that line would probably be missing, and you'd get the warning message.

Answer (score 0):

This means you didn't set your app `rootViewController`.
First remove these lines from your code-

```
[self.window addSubview:tempNav.view];  
[self.window addSubview:navController.view];  
[self.window addSubview:navController1.view];  
[self.window addSubview:navController2.view];  
[self.window addSubview:navController3.view];
```

and in your code you're taking `UITabBarController` but didn't initialize its `viewController`'s Array so do this -

```
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:tempNav, navController, navController1, navController2, navController3, nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: I need to do like this: First my app should show login screen. After entering in to the app, I need to show one view with tabbar. In that view So many buttons will be there, and when we clicking these button it should show respective viewcontrollers without a tabbar. Thats why i added those navigation controllers to the window.

Comment: YES, Dont add your navigation controller many times on window. If you want to set navigation controller with tabbarcontroller then do this in this way ...

Comment: where you mentioned this in your question ? You should write it in your question.... for login screen make firstView as rootViewController of your app and then in secondView controller viewDidLoad: method you can add this tabbar like [self.view addSubView:tabBarController.View];